# Log file for access denied / not shared?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, permissions, logging

Is there a log file where we can see if users try to access sites/pages they don't have access to or that haven't been shared with them?

Answer (score 2):

The SharePoint log preserve some information related to **Unauthorized Access Tries** that saved in the log file as `"Sending HTTP response 401 - text/plain:401 UNAUTHORIZED"`

But, Unfortunately, the `UserIdentityName` is not preserved, it showed as null.

---

The entry log for  **Unauthorized Access** looks like:

```
07/12/2017 12:03:23.34  w3wp.exe (0x464C)     0x2398 SharePoint Foundation          General  b6p2 Medium   Sending HTTP response 401 - text/plain:401 UNAUTHORIZED. 6b83049e-3013-f067-48e5-5bee64a22c59
```